# 'Body onload' not working in IE6?

Tags: javascript, html, onload-event

The `<body onload="sample()">` is working in all other browsers except in IE6. `window.onload` also did not work in IE6. The code is as follows,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<script type="application/javascript"> 
function sample() 
{
alert("hi"); 
} 
</script> 
</head>
<body onload="sample()"> ..... </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `<script type="application/javascript">` to `<script type="text/javascript">`, and it works!

Comment: @polin who says? why? it says on the "ask question" page that it's fine to answer your own questions "q&a style".

Comment: I know it. But here is a thing. Put a tough question you know the answer already. Then give answer and people will vote you up. what a nice way to get reputation. The rule set by StackOverflow is not a universal truth. Even in universal truths......there are bugs

Comment: @polin : Who sets the universal truth? either u / me / somebody... a human. Bugs / mistakes are natural!

Answer (score 0):

With `<!DOCTYPE html>`, I believe the script type attribute is optional, if the script is Javascript.

Comment: @James : I tried with <!DOCTYPE html>, it did not work then. Only after changing the script type I got it worked.